# Build failing after moving from yarn 1.22.19 to 3.6.3

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs, yarn-workspaces, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin, webpack-3.6

Before updating to yarn 3.6.3, I was using yarn 1.22.19 with webpack (with vue2) 3.6 and I had no issues with the `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin (version: ^1.1.1)` while running the build command.

But now after updating to yarn version, I am facing issues with the `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`

In local while switching the plugin versions from 1.1.1 till 1.3.0, I didn't face any errors whereas on jenkins its throwing me the below error

```
[1m[33mWARNING in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tms-docker-build/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tms-docker-build/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/modules/integrations/entityDetails.vue
91:25-42 "export 'integrationColumn' was not found in '@/constants/integrations'
 @ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tms-docker-build/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tms-docker-build/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/modules/integrations/entityDetails.vue
 @ ./src/components/modules/integrations/entityDetails.vue
 @ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tms-docker-build/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tms-docker-build/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/modules/integrations/index.vue
 @ ./src/components/modules/integrations/index.vue
 @ ./src/router/integration.js
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in static/js/56.dbbe5de848773c1620db.js from UglifyJs
undefined[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in static/js/109.2e1f31d0d6677f426e3c.js from UglifyJs
undefined[39m[22m

[1m[31mERROR in static/js/app.6f2ff31dbbfa1131528f.js from UglifyJs
undefined[39m[22m

  Build failed with errors.
```

After which when I updated the plugin version to `2.0.0`,
I started getting the below error on my local itself

```
/Users/aaa/Documents/Code/aaa-app/frontend/xyz/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:321
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(plugin, compilation => {
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'compilation')
    at UglifyJsPlugin.apply (/Users/aaa/Documents/Code/aaa-app/frontend/xyz/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:321:20)
    at Compiler.apply (/Users/aaa/Documents/Code/aaa-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:375:16)
    at webpack (/Users/aaa/Documents/Code/aaa-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:33:19)
    at /Users/aaa/Documents/Code/aaa-app/frontend/shipper/build/build.js:20:3
    at next (/Users/aaa/Documents/Code/aaa-app/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:83:7)
    at CB (/Users/aaa/Documents/Code/aaa-app/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:119:9)
```

I am not sure is there a specific version of `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` that works for my usecase. Please help!!

Thanks in advance